Google Play Console Ad ID Permission Issue: Unable to Publish Despite Manifest Changes
I haven't been able to solve this problem for days. The issue is that Google Play Console has been asking me to make an update for several days because they've changed their policies up to a certain date. Here's what they said:
'With Android 13 (API 33), the advertising ID is changing.
Apps that use the advertising ID and target Android 13 or later must declare the com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID permission in their app manifest. If you don't add this permission, your advertising ID will be reset. As a result, when trying to access the ID, a string of zeros will be returned instead. More information.
We use this declaration to ensure your app complies with Play Console policies.
If you declare that your app uses the advertising ID, we will block versions of your app targeting Android 13 that don't include the com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID permission in the manifest file. When we block these versions, we will remind you to add the permission. If your release doesn't require the advertising ID, you can skip the error and proceed with the release. You can also update the declaration to disable advertising ID release errors.'**
I completed this declaration and marked "Yes," stating that I use Google AdMob, and I also added the following statement to my manifest file as requested:
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID"/>
But it still didn’t work. I have multiple manifest files in my project, so I even added it to all of them, yet it still didn’t work. Some people suggested enabling the custom manifest in the Publish Settings and writing it there, but when I do that, I can’t build.
I marked the declaration as "No" and tried to publish, but it still didn’t remove this error.
If anyone is knowledgeable on this subject and could help, I’d greatly appreciate it!
Additionally, my project includes the following packages:
1-) GooglePlayGamesPlugin-0.10.14.unitypackage
2-) GoogleMobileAds-v9.2.0.unitypackage
3-) com.google.play.assetdelivery-1.9.1.unitypackage
Additionally, when I upload the AAB file and try to publish, it tells me:
'Your advertising ID declaration on Play Console indicates that your app uses the advertising ID. However, one of your active builds is missing the com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID permission in its manifest file.'
